# WebGL's zBuffer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

Does WebGL have a zBuffer or depth?

So here's my problem:

[image: problem]

The cube is being cropped or not being rendered properly. Setting the 'z' coordinates beside 0 and 1 results to object / geometry being cropped / cut.
Additionaly I've already implemented this on C++ and it works properly just porting it webGL and OpenGL ES.
Here's my persepective view configuration:

```
mat4.perspective(45.0, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 1000.0, pMatrix);
```

also tried setting the zFar to a much more larger value but the result are the same.

Here's the code that I used for vector translation:

```
mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, 2.0]);
```

and also tried this to check if there's a problem on the mat4.translate function this:

```
var x = 0.0, y = 0.0, z = 2.0;
var position = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    x, y, z, 1,
];

mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, position);
```

Also check and tried setting the values directly in Vertex Shader:

```
gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition.x, aVertexPosition.y, 2.0, 1.0);
```

Update:
Also set to enabled the DEPTH_TEST.

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
```

Comment: Of course it has a zbuffer. If it didn't pretty much none of the demos you see around the net would work.  Post your code somewhere like jsfiddle.net

Comment: Already thought of that, so I tried to analyze and disassemble the THREE.js source code. But couldn't find anything. But finally I solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved it, the cause of the problem is due to invalid argument parameters and outdated tutorials on the internet regarding usage of the gl-matrix.js library.

```
mat4.perspective(45.0, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 1000.0, pMatrix);
```

whereas of the new gl-matrix parameters should be like this:

```
mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45.0, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 1000.0);
```

After checking the correct documentation of the JS library.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a projection, you normally look from the origin in the direction of the negative z-axis. So I think you need a translation by a negative value in z-direction to get your geometry in view, while you translate by `[0.0, 0.0, 2.0]`.

You say you're trying to draw a cube, but your vertex shader hardwires all z-coordinates to `2.0`. You can't really get any kind of 3-dimensional shape if you're using the same z-coordinate for all vertices. Well, you technically could, but I doubt that this is what you want.